# Reception of numerical infinities

Tags: terminology, numerical-analysis

A group of computer scientists associated with numerical analyst Yaroslav Sergeyev have published numerous publications recently on a scheme proposed by Sergeyev that uses terms like *Infinity Computer*, *numerical infinitesimal* and *numerical infinity*, claiming that the approach facilitates the solution of many problems.

The mathematicians (including logicians) have been for the most part [sceptical](https://mathoverflow.net/q/226277/28128) but there are a few exceptions, such as [Elemer Rosinger](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=xqaRjdjkxvUC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=true) and [Gabriele Lolli](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriele_Lolli). How have these ideas been received by computer science professionals?

Note. On 19 dec '17 a [retraction page](http://retractionwatch.com/2017/12/19/editors-chief-math-journal-resign-controversial-paper) was created for this issue.

Comment: In my opinion you probably won't get help here. However I am not sure where you should go. Keep checking other sites. Something might pop up.

Comment: If the MathOverflow answers say it's nonsense, I'd tend to believe it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here.  This site is for technical questions about computer science.  Asking for a summary of how something is perceived by the entire community of computer scientists might not be answerable, especially if it is an esoteric issue that most computer scientists might never have heard of.  As such, I don't see how this question is going to be answerable, short of a poll of all computer science professionals on this topic (which probably hasn't been done).  Are you able to edit the question to ask a technical question that is objectively answerable?

Comment: @D.W., I personally have published widely on infinitesimals and infinite numbers both from technical mathematical point of view as well as historical and philosophical point of view; see [list of publications on infinitesimals](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html), including articles in *Journal of Symbolic Logic*, *Erkenntnis*, and *Studia Leibnitiana*. I have therefore been naturally interested in Sergeyev's project on infinitesimals and infinite numbers.  I must say I have been disappointed not only by a lack of precision of his discussions of infinitesimals and infinite...

Comment: ... numbers, but also by a rather palpable sense of what seems like deliberate obfuscation in his articles. However, it is possible that I am misreading this since I read it as a mathematician, not a computer scientist, a field where my expertise is limited to using email :-) Therefore I am interested in the views of the participants in this panel on the technical details of Sergeyev's discussion of infinitesimals and infinite numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the paper's

- ["Numerical infinities and infinitesimals: Methodology, applications, and repercussions on two Hilbert problems"](http://wwwinfo.deis.unical.it/yaro/EMSS_Sergeyev.pdf), Yaroslav D. Sergeyev (2017),

and it's basically a discussion on the author's "*grossone*" approach that they've been pushing for quite a while now (at least since 2004).

The *tl;dr* on it is that they're proposing a slightly [abstracted data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), kinda like how [complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) data types generalize [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) data types, except this one's focused on infinities instead of [imaginaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).

The author seems to want CPU's to include support for *grossone*'s in their [arithmetic logic units (ALU's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit), e.g. as specified in their [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US7860914).  The author's website and publications seem to focus on applied use in [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization); they seem to justify their work in terms of theoretical work as an afterthought.

Some of the [harshest criticism](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00160.pdf) seems to come from folks who're knocking it as-though the author were trying to report their work as some new theory, arguing that it's weaker and less sophisticated than prior work, e.g. [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).  The weird part about this is that, as far as I can tell, that's what the author wanted to do; they're trying to make an abstract data type to replace [floating-point data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for common calculation units, not solve the mysteries of the universe.

In general, I'd expect folks who get the author's intent to receive it with a bit of a yawn.  The arguments for modifying mainstream ALU's don't seem too compelling, and at-current there's likely not much demand for custom CPU's that implement it.

The author appears to have implemented *grossone*'s at a software level, kinda like how computers do complex-number operations.  Since they're using a [non-primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) numeric data type, their calculations'll be slower for it; but if they distribute the [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) and can demonstrate how it's worth the performance hit in some useful applications, some folks might start using it in those cases.

In short, it looks like the controversial proposal's for an abstract data type that includes infinities for use in common calculations.  It looks like applied work rather than theoretical, a misunderstanding which seems to have ruffled some feathers; however, at the end of the day if the authors can show that it's useful in real-life coding scenarios and make it available, then folks might use it.

Comment: The paper's honestly kinda funny.  I mean the dude was apparently trying to patent _grossone_'s for deployment in ALU's back in 2004; since then, he seems to have been pressured into explaining why his concept of infinities is valid in theoretical arenas.  But, it seems like he's doing it because people're demanding that he explain his work in classical terms; the author himself seems to care little for theoretical stuff and focuses almost exclusively on applied math throughout [his many publications](http://wwwinfo.deis.unical.it/yaro/list_pub.html).

Comment: Apparently there are many calculators today where symbolic calculation with a symbol for infinity or infinitesimal is used.  Is there a danger that one day they may have to defend themselves against legal challenges based on Sergeyev's patents?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Seems like patents can be used as weapons to extract money in all sorts of scenarios, from legitimate to absurd, but I guess that that's a wider problem at there're a ton of patents out there for fairly general stuff.  In this case, I think that patent was for ALU's and not software (none of this is legal advice, etc.), so I'd guess that it wouldn't apply.  I dunno if that'd necessarily prohibit a patent troll who might later acquire the patent from trying anyway, though I'd be skeptical about such a patent-holder's odds in court.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I'd guess that the patent-holder in this case might have a chance if they sue someone who makes a specialized hardware unit that processes a data type that includes infinities like the one proposed in the patent, though since common floating-point data types already have positive and negative infinities, presumably it'd have to be numeric infinities.  But then there'd be issues like if the patent's claims might be invalidated in court.

Comment: perhaps it's better to quote the EMS Surveys page of the paper, with a 
a link to the statement by the editorial board: http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=2308-2151&vol=4&iss=2&rank=3

Comment: Is the abstract data type ever actually clearly described? The examples all seem to indicate it's just finite precision (formal) power series arithmetic, but this is completely at odds with the exposition which presents it as... well... *some new theory*.

Comment: @Hurkyl Dunno; looks like this would've been most directly described back around 2003/2004 when the author put out a book on the topic along with a patent.  Kinda weird that such a highly publicized thing is still getting major publications 14 years later; without looking too far into it, my suspicion's that they're trying to justify the validity of their approach to garner support for its implementation.

Comment: @Hurkyl To be honest, I'm working on a mathematical operating system that's kinda like a generalized version of Mathematica (though a lot cooler!).  And to make it work well, I've had to abstract numerics quite a bit, including infinities.  Like this author, I didn't start from hyperreals or other existing systems because they're a bit bloated; it's been easier to just make the concepts from scratch.  I mean, none of this stuff's that complicated in the first place, ya know?

Comment: @Nat is your work on the generalized version of Mathematica publicly available?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Afraid not.  The business model's basically to get a working product line together and disrupt existing offerings.  I suspect that it's going to be a pretty tight closed-source model for the foreseeable future after initial release.  The idea's to have drop-in replacements for existing popular titles (like Mathematica) to gain market share.  From there, the plan's to use it as a back-end for AI stuff.

Comment: Presumably this is going ot be available to universities for purchase?  @Nat

Comment: @MikhailKatz Yeah, I'll almost certainly have deep discounts for academic users.  Short-term, I expect academic users to be quick to adopt it, so they're an initial target market.

Comment: Is the name of the package a secret at this point?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Hah, honestly I don't have a public name for it yet.  Back when I started working on it, I called it "_Expression_".  Later I switched to "_Math System_".  Then that got shortened to "_Maths_".  But, I figure that the primary system itself'll be more of an invisible back-end; most users'll see particular apps built on-top of it.  I figure it'll probably get renamed before public release.

Comment: Very mysterious :-)  How does your work connect with that of Shamseddine and coauthors?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Afraid I don't know of their work; what sort of stuff do they write about?

Comment: They seem to have an implementation based on Levi-Civita fields.  Just about everything I know is mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2634548/72694). @Nat

Comment: Incidentally, we now have solid evidence of Sergeyev's obstinacy.  Even after getting his butt kicked at EMS SMS, he is still citing that text as a legitimate publication [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01408). @Nat